# dynamically add fields to find() mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

Hi i am working with mongoDB , i am trying to crate a dynamic object and pass as an argument to the find()

my object is like this

**Library**

```
var search = {};
if(data.orderId) {

    search["_id"] = { $in: data.orderId.split(",") } ;
}if(data.path) {

    search["stops.districtId"] = data.path;
}if(data.special) {

    search["special.option"] = { $in: data.special.split(",") } ;
}if(data.userInfo) {

    search["UserId"] = data.userInfo;
}
```

then i will pass my search objet to the query like this

**Model**

```
                var col = db.collection( CustomerOrderModel.collection() );
                col.find(
                            {
                                serviceType:data.serviceType,
                                **search**
                            }
                    ).skip(data.skip).limit(data.limit).sort(data.sort).toArray(function(err, res) {

                    if (err) {

                        reject( err );
                    } else {

                        resolve( res );
                    }
                });
```

the problem here is when i console.log my search object i can see

```
'special.option': { '$in': [ 'ROUND_TRIP' ] } }
```

my $in is wrapped with quotes . so my query doesn't work .

if i directly type `"special.option": { $in: [ 'ROUND_TRIP' ] } }` in my query it is working correctly  .

i m trying to built this search object because i have multiple fields to search with complex logic . i don't want to do these in my
 model , so i wil create the search object in my library .

is there any possible ways to this , thanks in advance .

Comment: Are you seriously passing your search object into the query like this `{
                                serviceType:data.serviceType,
                                **search**
                            }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the search object part of the query by adding the extra filters into the search object. As you are currently doing

```
col.find({
    serviceType:data.serviceType,
    search
})
```

this is interprated as

```
col.find({
    serviceType:data.serviceType,
    { 'special.option': { '$in': [ 'ROUND_TRIP' ] } } 
})
```

You should be able to add the `serviceType` filter to your existing search object using the square bracket notation as follows:

```
search["serviceType"] = data.serviceType;
```

then you can pass that object in your query:

```
var col = db.collection( CustomerOrderModel.collection() );
search["serviceType"] = data.serviceType;
col.find(search)
   .skip(data.skip)
   .limit(data.limit)
   .sort(data.sort)
   .toArray(function(err, res) {
        if (err) {  reject( err ); } 
        else {  resolve( res ); }
    });
```

Comment: yep , the was the problem :) :) , thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

That is not the problem.

```
console.log({ "special.option": { $in: [ 'ROUND_TRIP' ] } });
```

gives

```
{ 'special.option': { '$in': [ 'ROUND_TRIP' ] } }
```

so this is correct.

In your code you just write `**search**` in the most critical part, but try this:

```
search["serviceType"] = data.serviceType;
col.find( search )
```

Comment: oops , seems like the error is because i  wrap the find with {} . if i try your code with col.find({ search }) it is not working but if i try col.find(search) it works . :) , thank you very much